# Python hang on first import

Tags: python, import

I copied a partial Python script from a benchmark scripts and tried to execute it after making modifications. The problem is, it is hanging once it is started.

The Python script is:

```
# !/usr/bin/python

# =============================
# initialize & configure
# =============================
#import shlex
#import fnmatch
import os
import subprocess
import resource
import os, sys, cPickle, time, threading, signal

from errno import EEXIST
from os.path import join
from subprocess import Popen
#from domain import Record
from threading import Timer



def measure(commandline):

#   r,w = os.pipe()
   forkedPid = os.fork()

   if forkedPid: # read pickled measurements from the pipe

      print "Parent proc start and the child pid: ", forkedPid
 #     os.close(w); rPipe = os.fdopen(r); r = cPickle.Unpickler(rPipe)
 #     measurements = r.load()
 #     rPipe.close()
      os.waitpid(forkedPid,0)
      print "Parent proc end"
      return "------------"

   else: 
      # Sample thread will be destroyed when the forked process _exits
      class Sample(threading.Thread):

         def __init__(self,program):
            threading.Thread.__init__(self)
            self.setDaemon(1)
            self.timedout = False 
            self.p = program
            self.maxMem = 0
            self.childpids = None   
            self.start() 

         def run(self):
            try:              
               remaining = maxtime
               delay=0.01
               print "Start run deman thread: ", remaining, "delay", delay
               while remaining > 0:                                   
                  res = resource.getrusage(resource.RUSAGE_CHILDREN)

                  time.sleep(delay)                    
                  remaining -= delay
                  print "\n res: ",res, " and remaining is: ", remaining

               else:
                  self.timedout = True
                  os.kill(self.p, signal.SIGKILL) 
            except OSError, (e,err):
                print "Error ", err


      try:

         print "Child proc ", commandline

         # only write pickles to the pipe
       #  os.close(r); wPipe = os.fdopen(w, 'w'); w = cPickle.Pickler(wPipe)

         start = time.time()

         # print "commandLine: ", commandline, " remaining: ",remaining
         # spawn the program in a separate process
         p = Popen(commandline,stdout=outFile,stderr=errFile,stdin=inFile, shell=True)


         # start a thread to sample the program's resident memory use
         t = Sample( program = p.pid )
         print "Child ......"
         # wait for program exit status and resource usage
         rusage = os.wait3(0)
         print 'rusage: ', rusage
         elapsed = time.time() - start

       #  m.userSysTime = rusage[2][0] + rusage[2][1]
       #  m.maxMem = t.rusage
       #  m.cpuLoad = "%"
       #  m.elapsed = elapsed
         print "Child proc end"

      except KeyboardInterrupt:
          print "keyBordInterrupt..."
          os.kill(p.pid, signal.SIGKILL)

      except ZeroDivisionError, (e,err): 
          print " error ZeroDiv: "

      except (OSError,ValueError), (e,err):
          print " error ", e
      finally:
          print "Here is finally section. "
         #w.dump(m)
         # wPipe.close()

         # Sample thread will be destroyed when the forked process _exits
          os._exit(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "Start now...."
#measure("jruby  \/tmp/test.rb")
```

When I use `ps -ef | grep MyAccount`, I find the interpreter will hang on the first `import instruction:

```
  MyAccount    16934 16933  0 12:08 pts/19   00:00:00 import os
```

/tmp/test.rb is a one-line Ruby script (`puts "hello"`), and it should not caused any problem as it has been commented out.

I ran `ps -ef | grep MyAccount` for three mintues, and this one is ALWAYS there. Also, there is not any output in the console, where I expected to see `Start now....`.

Comment: How do you know that it is hanging on the first import?

Comment: I keep running ``ps -ef | grep MyAccount`` for 3 mintues, and this one is ALWAYS there..

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't realize your file was called `MyAccount` for some reason. My mistake!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because your code is not interpreted as a Python script but as a Bash script.

The first line should be

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

instead of

```
# !/usr/bin/python
```

You can skip this line and simply run your program using

```
python <your_script.py>
```

instead of

```
./<your_script.py>
```

I also think you read the `ps` results incorrectly.

The last column of `ps -ef` is the name of the command, definatelly not a line of the script, and the first one, `MyAccount`, is the name of the user.

So this `ps` output means that process `import os` is hanging. There is an application called import in some Linux distributions, see `man import`. If you try to execute it from the shell:

```
$import os
```

it simply waits for input forever (until interupted), and that is what happened to you.